# Efficient way to get name/MT of ValueTypes not listed in !dumpheap -stat

Tags: clr, windbg, value-type, sos, dbghelp

I'm working my way around the SOS commands and their output, but I noticed there doesn't seem to be a way to get really all types that are currently in use somehow. The best way so far is `!dumpheap -stat`, but it only lists types for which there are instances.
However, when a ValueType is never boxed, that type will not show up on `!dumpheap -stat`. (Which isn't surprising, as they aren't allocated on the heap.)

So my question is:
Are there any efficient ways to figure out which additional ValueTypes currently exist?
I mean, I could load them on-demand when inspecting individual heap objects (something like `!dumpvc <mt> <address>` based on `!do <address>` output), but for displayed statistics it would be nice to find the types through some simpler means than looking at (instances/class definitions of) all known classes to figure out whether they use any additional ValueTypes.

Comment: Strange question.  Why would knowing that a program uses System.Int32 be useful at all?  !dumpmodule -mt lists all the types in a module, including value types.

Comment: I'm not really after Int32 and similar basic types. The composite types with more than a single member are the interesting parts, for example `System.Drawing.Color`, which consits of a string, a long and two shorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any efficient way to do this. In other words, I ended up checking each type `!DumpHeap -stat` returned for whether it is a struct array or contains struct fields. In both cases I need to recursively check if the new-found struct type contains any struct fields as well. In that case recursion is required, unless I've already seen the struct type.

`!DumpModule -mt` is not option, btw. For example, I see `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``, but nothing that would represent e.g. the List class.